# Should user data be encrypted on the client or server side?

Tags: security

I have a small question to ask you! When a user registers on a site, his password is stored, encrypted, in the database. Encryption is possible in PHP thanks to different functions, notably password_encrypt from memory. In this case, the encryption operates on the server side.
BUT
we can imagine that we encrypt the password in JavaScript, so on the client side, and that we send to the server the already encrypted password!

My question is the following: when the encryption is done on the server side, is there any way to intercept the unencrypted password ON THE SERVER, just before it is encrypted (spy scripts, etc.). In this case, perhaps client-side encryption should be preferred, so if the server is controlled by an attacker, it does not compromise user security.

Also, for the user's trust, isn't client-side encryption better?

What about known sites? Do they encrypt data on the server or client side?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the server is controlled by the attacker passwords do no longer matter. If I can control the server I can log in as any user anyway. But the more common scenario is a database leak where all encrypted passwords are leaked - if the client encrypts the password the encrypted thing now ***is*** the password and if your server stores that information and looses it somebody can just log in as that user sending that encrypted text. You only encrypt client side if the server should not know anything, e.g. end2end encryption for messaging.

Comment: Additionally note that passwords should be *hashed*, not *encrypted*. Basically an exact duplicate (and the better suited SE site for this question): https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/https-security-should-password-be-hashed-server-side-or-client-side